# keystore file exists but its empty in android key store

Tags: android

I'm trying to get keyhash for facebook application.For this i've installed openssl.and now trying to get hash key from command line.I've also generated .apk file and keystore for an app.

But when i try i' getting **java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: E:\key**

where E:\key is folder where i've generated my keystore.
E:\apk is folder where my apk file is kept.

Please help me...This is first time i'm doing this and not getting it

Thanks in advance...